# restore under RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, yum, restore

Say there's an application that install to `/opt/` directory. I update it with `yum`. I do a full server backup, that is all the file systems (/opt/ maps to the root directory). Now, I discover a bug post upgrade or have the need for whatever reason to restore to the pre upgrade state. Should I:

a) restore the whole /opt/application directory along with its files and sub-directories;
b) perform a complete system restore to the last backup 
c) or perform a `yum` roll back [How to use yum history to roll back an update in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 , 7?](http://How%20to%20use%20yum%20history%20to%20roll%20back%20an%20update%20in%20Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%206%20,%207?)

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum` (or `dnf` in RHEL-7) to roll-back (remove) the application. This keeps the package repository consistent with the software installed.

Comment: Ok but what if the update made also changes to a MySQL DB on a remote server ? Doing a yum roll-back will not revert the changes made to the DB, right ?

Comment: Correct. The rollback is for the software package.

Comment: Thank you. So I'd would have to perform a yum roll-back + a DB restore to get the previous good know state?

Comment: Yes, the yum/dnf rollback takes care of the software. You need to deal with the database independently.